# Java Byte Code manipulation: Adding a method to a jdk abstract class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

**Problem:**
I need to add a method to the java.util.prefs.Preferences abstract class, the reasons are as follows:

1. I have implemented a clusterable preferences implementation and i need to enrich it with more than basic api that java.util.prefs.Preferences provides.
2. I do not want to break the usage contract, i.e., a client gets the Preference implementation and uses the Preferences api only(obviously the enriched one).

How can I add a method to an existing Java bytecode?

Comment: Spring and Hibernate are written with Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) and Dependency Injection in mind.  Preferences isn't.

Comment: I believe this would involve tinkering with system class loader, which sounds extremely difficult, especially in something like a web application. Not to mention that if it is for a library, you should **not** do something like this.

Comment: Alternatively, could you just create a subclass of `Preferences` through a subclass of [`PreferencesFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/PreferencesFactory.html) and set the system property `java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory`? This would allow you to define your custom, enriched `Preferences` class and have it instantiated as the default `Preferences` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `java.util.prefs.Preferences`, you are out of luck. This class cannot be instrumented unless you change the classes that are put onto [the bootstrap class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html). And even if, note that is considered a breach of the JVM's user license agreement to ship an installation with a changed bootstrap class path.

Normally, you can change a class during load time using a Java agent. This way, you could add methods. However, the `Preferences` class is used by the JVM internally and it gets loaded **before** an agent would be loaded. This way, the agent cannot be applied.

Alternatively, the [`Instrumentation` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) would allow you to change a loaded class at runtime. Using this approach, it is however illegal to add methods which is why this does not work either.

As a third option, you could consider to implement a child-first class loader that shadows the `Preferences` class but no class loader other than the bootstrap class loader is allowed to define a class in a `java.*` package. Thus, this does not work either.

What you want to do instead:

1. Write a wrapper object, some `EnhancedPreferences` that delegate to another `Preferences` object it keeps in a field.
2. Write a utility class which operates on a `Preferences` object using `static` methods.

Comment: Good note on the breach of license, but otherwise this answer doesn't seem to address direct bytecode modification through libraries like ASM, which (unless `Preferences` is indeed a special case here too) can modify *any* class, even if it comes from the JVM.

Comment: Yes, you can read the class file and modifiy it but you are not able to load the modified byte code to actually represent the bootstrap class loader's `java.util.prefs.Preferences` class. As my answer states, you cannot hot swap the code or intercept the loading of the class as any agent is only attached after the class is already loaded.

Comment: Eventually, this was taken care with the approach Rafael mentioned using a wrapper.